# Oracle merge two rows as single row with more columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have two tables Employee, Employeerows. I have to pull the employee records who has role 2 or 3.
I have the query below.

```
SELECT
    E.ID,
    E.NAME,
    ER.PHONE,
    ER.ADDRESS,
    ER.ROLE
    
FROM
 EMPLOYEE E LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEEROWS ER ON E.ID = ER.ID WHERE ER.ROLE_ID IN (2,3)
```

This returns either 1 or 2 records for each employee

```
ID      NAME        PHONE       ADDRESS     ROLE
1       ABC         9898989     ABC NJ       2
1       ABC         7878787     ABC XJ       3
2       DEF         7898765     DEF NJ       2
```

But I have to merge two records into one for that employee with phone number and address as separate columns if the employee has 2 records. **My result should like this.**

```
ID      NAME        PHONE       ALT_PHONE     ADDRESS      ALT_ADDESS   
1       ABC         9898989     7878787        ABC NJ       ABC XJ          
2       DEF         7898765                    DEF NJ
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  But the `left join` seems superfluous.  You only want to use the `left join` if you want "employees" that have no rows.

It *appears* from your data that "2" corresponds to the primary address and "3" to the alternate:

```
select e.id, e.name,
       max(case when er.role_id = 2 then er.phone end) as phone,
       max(case when er.role_id = 3 then er.phone end) as alt_phone,
       max(case when er.role_id = 2 then er.address end) as address,
       max(case when er.role_id = 3 then er.address end) as alt_address
from employee e join
     employeerows er
     on e.id = er.id
where er.role_id in (2, 3)
group by e.id, e.name;
```

However, if "2" could be missing, then you would phrase this as:

```
select e.id, e.name,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then er.phone end) as phone,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then er.phone end) as alt_phone,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then er.address end) as address,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then er.address end) as alt_address
from employee e join
     (select er.*,
             row_number() over (partition by er.id order by er.role_id) as seqnum
      from employeerows er
      where er.role_id in (2, 3)
     ) er
     on e.id = er.id
group by e.id, e.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select e.id, e.name,
    max(case when er.role_id = 2 then er.phone   end) as phone,
    max(case when er.role_id = 3 then er.phone   end) as alt_phone,
    max(case when er.role_id = 2 then er.address end) as address,
    max(case when er.role_id = 3 then er.address end) as alt_address
from employee e 
left join employeerows er on e.id = er.id where er.role_id in (2,3)
group by e.id, e.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation. But your query is **not doing `LEFT OUTER JOIN`** but it is `INNER JOIN` as you have used the `er.role_id in (2,3)` in `WHERE` clause.

Use the following aggreagation technique to fetch the desired result:

```
SELECT
    E.ID,
    E.NAME,
    MIN(ER.PHONE),
    CASE WHEN MIN(ER.PHONE) <> MAX(ER.PHONE) THEN MAX(ER.PHONE) END AS ALT_PHONE,
    MIN(ER.ADDRESS),
    CASE WHEN MIN(ER.ADDRESS) <> MAX(ER.ADDRESS) THEN MAX(ER.ADDRESS) END AS ALT_ADDRESS
FROM EMPLOYEE E 
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEEROWS ER ON E.ID = ER.ID 
                   AND ER.ROLE_ID IN (2,3) -- added it in the join condition
GROUP BY E.ID, E.NAME;
```